# shiny checkbox unchecks - cross-referring to inputs in same renderUI call

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I intended to have some optional extra buttons appearing in my shiny app using renderUI. I would prefer to have new buttons inserted in the one and same renderUI call. I wrote a renderUI expession were the second button only is rendered if input of fist button is not null and(&&) is TRUE. It does not work as first button rapidly unchecks itself again whenever checked. I made a solution by splitting into two renderUI calls.

**My question are:**

- Why exactly does the first code piece fail?
- Would it be possible to achieve what the second code piece does in only one renderUI call?

.

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(
  uiOutput("checkUI")
)
server = function(input,output) {
  output$checkUI = renderUI({
    list(
      checkboxInput('check1',"check me first"),
      if(!is.null(input$check1)&&input$check1==T)  {
        checkboxInput('check2',"check me to win") 
      } else { 
        NULL
      }
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

but this works...

```
ui = fluidPage(
  uiOutput("checkUI"),
  uiOutput("textUI")

)
server = function(input,output) {
  #UI first button
  output$checkUI = renderUI({
    list(
      checkboxInput('check1',"check me first")
    )
  })

  #UI second button
  output$textUI = renderUI({
    list(
      if(!is.null(input$check1) && input$check1)
        checkboxInput('check2',"check me to win") else NULL
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: `checkboxInput` should be in ui.r as oppose to server part. To change the statues of checkboxinput on server side, chek the `updateCheckboxInput`.

Comment: To place the checkboxInput in ui.R is probably not what I want, because ui.R is static. I use renderUI to explicitly control the rendering of the checkbox(s) from the server side. Sometimes the box should not be there. Sometimes (i in 1:10) checkboxes should be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Your first piece of code fails because the renderUI runs every time there is a change in input, so when you check the first check box. Since you have:

`checkboxInput('check1',"check me first")`

The renderUI immediately resets the `input$check1` and then the `renderUI` is run again, unsetting the checkbox. This is why the second checkbox briefly flashes.

Luckily this is a common problem, so there is a Shiny solution to this with `conditionalPanel`s:

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(
  checkboxInput('check1',"check me first"),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.check1 == true",
    checkboxInput("check2", "check me to win")
  )
)
server = function(input,output){

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```